# Android GoogleSignIn API error Status{statusCode=NETWORK_ERROR, resolution=null}

Tags: android, google-signin, googlesigninaccount

Good Day! I'm having problems when using GoogleSignInApi. It works wonderful, when I'm using it over WIFI connection. But when I turn off WIFI, and use mobile data only, I'm getting the `GoogleSignInStatusCodes.NETWORK_ERROR` from `Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent` activity result.

I'm using Firebase UI for authentication, but I guess it has nothing to do with the module, as I'm getting the network error directly from the GoogleSignInApi.

This is how it looks like when I setup the SignInOptions:

```
String mClientId = activity.getString(R.string.default_web_client_id);
GoogleSignInOptions googleSignInOptions;

GoogleSignInOptions.Builder builder = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
.requestEmail()
.requestIdToken(mClientId);               

for (String scopeString : idpConfig.getScopes()) {
    builder.requestScopes(new Scope(scopeString));
}

if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
    builder.setAccountName(email);
}
googleSignInOptions = builder.build();

mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(activity)
.enableAutoManage(activity, AUTO_MANAGE_ID, this)
.addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, googleSignInOptions)
.build();
```

And this is how I launch the SignIn activity:

```
Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
activity.startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
```

And I get the `NETWORK_ERROR` here:

```
 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            if (result != null) {
                if (result.isSuccess()) {
                    mIDPCallback.onSuccess(createIDPResponse(result.getSignInAccount()));
                } else {
                    onError(result);
                }
            } else {
                onError("No result found in intent");
            }
        }
    }
```

On the keys, etc. I have configured everything correctly, as it is working fine over WIFI.

On permission end, I have all the permissions requested (and handled the Android 6.0 properly too)

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: Are you sure that you have not retched you max data quote? Could you please confirm that another application is working correctly over mobile data ?

Comment: Yes - all others were working fine except the ones using google play services because I disabled the background data for that service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that I've disabled the background data for Google Play Settings. This resulted that I had proper internet connection by default even on 3G, but the Google Play Services were blocked to access the internet, this prevented any GooglePlay service to run.